# Deprecated: Optional parameter $level declared before required parameter $message

Tags: php, deprecated, optional-parameters, required

This is the error message

> Deprecated: Optional parameter $level declared before required parameter $message is implicitly treated as a required parameter in C:\xampp\htdocs\School Management System\system\core\Common.php on line 350

```
{
    function log_message($level = 'error', $message,  $php_error = FALSE)
    {
        static $_log;

        if (config_item('log_threshold') == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        $_log =& load_class('Log');
        $_log->write_log($level, $message, $php_error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Optional parameters can only be at the end of the parameter list. So either give a default to `$message`, or remove the default from `$level`.